# como puedo validar si un objectId ingresado por el usuario es igual al que reposa en la db. estoy utilizando mongodb y fastapi

Tags: python, mongodb

```
@product.delete("/user/products/{id}", tags=["Products"])
async def delete_product(id: str):
    if(ObjectId(id).equals(id)):
        productEntity(client.local.product.find_one_and_delete(
            {"_id": ObjectId(id)}))
    else:
        return HTTPException(404, "Product not found")
```

estoy tratando de validad el valor que tiene un objectid con el metodo equals, no consigo mucha información de como sería la forma adecuada y poco a poco trato de adentarme a estas tecnologias, agradezco cualquier ayuda o explicación.

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas comparar el valor recibido con una instancia de [`ObjectId`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html#module-bson.objectid), en cambio puedes validar que el parámetro recibido sea realmente una cadena que represente un `ObjectId`.

Para lograrlo te puedes apoyar del método [`isvalid()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/objectid.html#bson.objectid.ObjectId.is_valid) de la Clase `ObjectId`.

Por ejemplo:

```py
import bson

@product.delete("/user/products/{id}", tags=["Products"])
async def delete_product(id: str):
    if not bson.ObjectId.is_valid(id):
        return HTTPException(400, "Invalid id")
    # ...
```

El método `is_valid` devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo de si la cadena pasada como argumento es una representación válida de un `ObjectId`.

Toma en cuenta que aunque el valor de `id` pasado sea válido, cabe la posibilidad que no exista ningún documento en tu colección que tenga dicho `id`.

Es muy distinto decir que un `id` no es válido a decir que un `id` no se encuentra en la colección. Es por ello que la lógica de tu implementación debe tomar en cuenta ambos casos.

El método [`find_one_and_delete`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_delete) devuelve el documento eliminado si el mismo ha sido encontrado en la colección, de lo contrario devuelve `None`.

Usando este método podemos saber si el `id` ha sido encontrado en la colección, y de esta forma podremos notificar al cliente si la operación ha dado resultado o no.

Tu código podría quedar parecido al siguiente:

```py
import bson

@product.delete("/user/products/{id}", tags=["Products"])
async def delete_product(id: str):
    if not bson.ObjectId.is_valid(id):
        # cuando el ID no es válido
        return HTTPException(400, "Invalid ID")

    # si llegamos aquí es porque el id es válido
    # ahora determinaremos si existe en la colección

    deleted_product = client.local.product.find_one_and_delete({"_id": bson.ObjectId(id)})

    if not deleted_product:
        # si el resultado es None, entonces el producto no fue encontrado
        return HTTPException(404, "Product not found")

    # si llegamos aquí es porque el producto fue encontrado y borrado
    # podemos continuar con el resto de la lógica
    productEntity(deleted_product)
    
    # ...
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.